# HIVE Boolean Filter

Tags: sql, filter, hive, boolean, impala

I am trying to filter a table in HIVE/IMPALA using a boolean column but somehow Im getting "Error while processing statement"

My query is something like this `select * from schema_name.table_name where boolean_col is TRUE`

Would like to know the proper query for this kind of filter. TIA

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax is `where boolean_col = True`

You do not need additional comparison, just use column as is, it is already boolean:

```
select * from schema_name.table_name 
 where boolean_col
```

And to select rows with boolean_col = False use `NOT`:

```
select * from schema_name.table_name 
 where NOT boolean_col
```

To check for NULL use `boolean_col is NULL`